# How to find when and to what an employee's location has changed and output both previous and current location?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: The below describes the 'before' state of the rows and columns. Here, User A had his location changed from Loc_1 to Loc_2 on effective date 27-FEB-18 03.04.04.764000000 PM.][image: This shows the desired result.]

From the original set of records, how do i bring the employees previous location,new location and from when this change is effective. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if an employee has, say, 2 or 3 previous locations?

Comment: @lurker - if you read the post, you will quickly understand that the first table is sample input, while the second is the desired output from those inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. Not tested, since you did not provide test data in a usable format. If an employee changed location several times, all changes will be shown. (You may want to order by `emp_id` and `eff_from_date` to make the output easier to read/use; I didn't do that.) I ignored the `emp_status` column since you didn't say anything about it; if it must be used, it would probably go in a `where` clause in the **sub**query. I also changed your column names to valid ones.

```
select emp_id, emp_name, prev_emp_location, new_emp_location, eff_from_date
from   (
         select emp_id, emp_name, emp_location as new_emp_location, eff_from_date,
                lag(emp_location) over (partition by emp_id order by eff_from_date)
                    as prev_emp_location
         from   your_table
       )
where  new_emp_location != prev_emp_location
;
```

The subquery uses the `lag()` analytic function to record the previous location (partitioned by `emp_id` and ordered chronologically); then the output can be used to simply filter for the rows where the previous location is not equal to the current one.